# How to change Jenkins system/environment variables

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, environment-variables

Hi I have installed Jenkins on windows 7 as service agent.

When I run shell command like `whoami` in the execute shell it shows a domain name as a user, when I run the same command through command prompt it shows system login user. Since the users are different I could not able to run batch files which are used to deploy the files from Jenkins build machine to other machines. Where as the same batch are getting executed when they are called in the windows command prompt.

I have struck here what have to be done.

I have modified in the system properties > advanced > environment variables > system variables
but this modification is not reflected in jenkins > manage jenkins > system information > system properties/environmental variables.

Can any one help me on how to solve this issue?

Comment: can anyone help me on this..no one faced this issue still..???